# Mongoose saving array as empty when not

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

First, here is the code:

Mongoose Schema

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

// Registration Form schema
var RegistrationFormSchema = new Schema;

RegistrationFormSchema.add({
  studentFirst: { type: String, required: true },
  studentLast: { type: String, required: true },
  studentGrade: { type: String, required: true },
  guardianFirst: { type: String, required: true },
  guardianLast: { type: String },
  guardianEmail: { type: String },
  courseString: { type: String },
  courseArray: { type: Array }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('RegistrationForm', RegistrationFormSchema);
```

Relevant API Route

```
  apiRouter.route('/registerNow')
    .post(function(req, res) {

      var newForm = new RegistrationForm();
      console.log(req.body);
      newForm.studentFirst = req.body.studentFirst;
      newForm.studentLast = req.body.studentLast;
      newForm.studentGrade = req.body.studentGrade;
      newForm.guardianFirst = req.body.guardianFirst;
      newForm.guardianLast = req.body.guardianLast;
      newForm.guardianEmail = req.body.guardianEmail;
      newForm.courseString = req.body.courseString;

      newForm.save();
  }
```

And this is inside of my controller, where I am making the request. Also making a request in Postman with the same response, so not sure if it is anything to do with how I am requesting, but want to include this to have more info for an answer.

```
$http.post('/api/registerNow', {
  'studentFirst': vm.courseInfo.studentFirst,
  'studentLast': vm.courseInfo.studentLast,
  'studentGrade': vm.courseInfo.studentGrade,
  'guardianFirst': vm.courseInfo.guardianFirst,
  'guardianLast': vm.courseInfo.guardianLast,
  'guardianEmail': vm.courseInfo.guardianEmail,
  'courseString': vm.courseInfo.courseString,
  'courseArray': ['asdasd', 'fasfasf', 'gasgasga']
});
```

Now that we have the relevant code, the question!

When I make my HTTP Post request to save to my database, it all saves, but it saves courseArray as an empty array '[]' no matter what, if it is empty or full.

I assume it's a Mongoose Schema issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your route you're not setting the `newForm.courseArray` property with the data from the request. Mongoose is probably setting the default value as an empty array.

Try using the following code

```
apiRouter.route('/registerNow')
    .post(function(req, res) {

        var newForm = new RegistrationForm();
        console.log(req.body);
        newForm.studentFirst = req.body.studentFirst;
        newForm.studentLast = req.body.studentLast;
        newForm.studentGrade = req.body.studentGrade;
        newForm.guardianFirst = req.body.guardianFirst;
        newForm.guardianLast = req.body.guardianLast;
        newForm.guardianEmail = req.body.guardianEmail;
        newForm.courseString = req.body.courseString;
        newForm.courseArray = req.body.courseArray; //This line is missing

        newForm.save();
    });
```